# Problem loading simple, valid page via jquery load() in IE - "E.location.protocol is null or not an object."

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, load

I'm really not sure what could be simpler. On click, IE refuses to load a page using the jQuery load() function. It just gives me an 'E.location.protocol' is null or not an object error within the jQuery code itself (1.4.4). Works in every other browser, of course.

I simplified the add_image.php to be a very simple, static page, which I checks as valid at http://validator.w3.org.

I have many of the other posts here about IE load problems, but it isn't a caching problem, or a validation problem.

So, I can't figure what I'm doing wrong here. Other than simply trying to code something simple for the world's most used browser without expecting it to not be a horrible, excruciating, frustrating experience.

```
$("#add-image-button").click(function(){
    $("#dialog").load('/admin_and_tools/forms/add_image.php?time=<?=time()?>');                                   
});
```

And ideas are greatly appreciated. I'm honestly not sure how to proceed if I can't count on something so simple as an ajax page load to happen in IE.

Comment: I don't know why you think it's _so_ simple. Did you try specifying a full, absolute URL? It seems like IE is looking for `http://`. Your approach should be valid as it stands, but trying this at least might help to narrow down the issue.

Comment: http://pinoytech.org/question/4821080/jquery-window-location-href-issue-in-ie-null-or-not-an-object-error-could-it-be

Comment: The link you provided at pinyotech is also my question. Maybe I can do the same thing I did that time, which is to change the jQuery code. But that seems a bit hacky.

Comment: @user399696: Yes, it's a question with an answer. Now why not respond to the other comments made?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you everyone for all your help.

As it turns out, I was making an very basic error (surprise, surprise), and have been trying to work around it for months without suspecting the real cause.

In one of my scripts, I had been redeclaring var location as a global, destroying the original. This only bothered IE for whatever reason, but it indeed was getting rid of this important variable.

Anyway, thanks to JSLint for helping me finally discover this, and thanks everyone for your help.

---

Please stop reading here to avoid listening to one more anti-microsoft rant:

I would like to add that every attempt at using any sort of debugger in Microsoft, either the built in one in IE, the downloadable Script Debugger, or even FirebugLite intended to help with debugging javascript on IE was useless - either giving false line numbers, not being able to find the source or not throwing any error at all. Not to mention the clunky UI of the I debugger, the graphical screw ups, the incessant redirects in Microsofts own website - everything I have tried was painful. Really, if I turned out a product like they do - god help me I'd starve to death.

Answer (score 0):

Is your jQuery code in PHP generated one? If not, I think `<?=time()?>` in the URL won't work.
I don't know if this can offend IE, but it might be a problem to pass `<` or `>` in the URL without escaping them.

If you want to prevent caching the `add_image.php` script you can use jQuery native option `cache`;

```
("#dialog").load('/admin_and_tools/forms/add_image.php', {
            -->  cache: false  <--
                 });
```

Comment: Yes, the jquery code gets written in a php page. It looks fine in in view source, and throws no errors. I removed it entirely and got the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a relative path instead of an absolute path.  Or, try using the full URL w/ the protocol:

`http://www.myurl.com`

Comment: Agreed. I think an absolute URL probably wants a proper URI with protocol etc.

Comment: Thank you, but unfortunately this has no effect. I still get the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Update your version of jQuery.

**Test it out with this script tag:**

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.5.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: No, unfortunately. Thanks though. IE is now giving me an error on line number of 183748392. IE debugger really couldn't be less helpful.